# Assign the labels of all 50 setosa flowers to an array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, scikit-learn

I'm new to python/numpy and I'm trying to play around with the Iris dataset from sklearn to see if I can create an array containing the 4 labels of all setosa flowers.

I find this pretty hard and I'm not really sure what to try, I know that the setosa flowers and the labels can be found in `Iris.data`, and I've been told that `np.where` might be useful here but other than that, I'm stuck. The shape should be (50,4) since there are 50 setosa flowers with 4 labels.

I've been thinking of first figuring out the 50 indices of the setosa flowers from `iris.target` (where `0 = setosa`) in hopes that those are positioned in the same index to those in `iris.data` but then I wouldn't really know how to use those 50 indices to retrieve those from `iris.data`.

I would really appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're 90% of the way there. `np.where` returns a tuple of indexes where the condition is true, which can be passed to the `data` portion of the `Bunch` object:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()

setosa = iris.data[np.where(iris.target == 0)]

print(setosa)
print(setosa.shape)
```

Summarized output:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 ...
 [4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2]
 [5.3 3.7 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.3 1.4 0.2]]

(50, 4)
```